# Compilation error when sending an object that expect to get a reference

Tags: c++, compilation, pass-by-reference

I have this small piece of code that doesn't compile, and I was wondering about the reasons more specifically why is push(new X) the problem?

Before that, I would like to ask what new X (with no identifier) really mean? does it create an object X with no identifier name? does it go through the constructor at all?

Secondly,

I might not understand the whole concept, but, push is a template class, right?
Since it contains a static T stack, the type T is consistent and can not be changed once a specific argument is sent, the first one, in this case int x. Is that correct?

Thirdly, 
following my second question, if it is correct then why push(y) do not flag a compiler error just like push(new X) does? i mean, x is an int type and y is a reference type.

I'd really appreciates if someone can clarify it for me.

Thanks, here it is:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    void push(T &t) {
    static const int CAPACITY = 20;
    static T stack[CAPACITY];
    static int size = 0;
    stack[size++] = t;
    cout << size;
    };
   class X {};

   void main()
   {
   int x = 3;
   int &y = x;
   push(x);
   push(new X);
   push(y);
 }
```

Comment: gold push is a template function.

Comment: gold The operator new returns pointer to a dynamically created object.

Comment: Please one question per question. And if your code does not compile show compiler error (first one is enough) and point to the line that produced it.

Comment: For `push (y)`, Google "reference collapsing"

Answer (score 1):

> and I was wondering about the reasons more specifically why is push(new X) the problem?

Because you declared type of your template function parameter as non const lvalue reference to `T`. To help programmers to avoid incorrect code language does not allow to bind temporaries to non const lvalue references. In your case:

```
new X
```

returns a temporary of type `X *` (pointer to X), your template function argument type `T` deduced to `X *` in this case and `t` is now lvalue reference to `X *` or `X *&` but language does not allow to bind temporary to an lvalue reference hense compilation error. Your second case is logically equal to this code:

```
 void pushX( X *&t ); // pushX accepts reference to pointer to X

 pushX( new X ); // you cannot bind a temporary returned by `new X` to lvalue reference `t`
```

It could be easier to understand if you use simple type like `int`:

```
int function_returns_int();

void push_int( int &ri );


push_int( function_returns_int() ); // compilation error, function_returns_int() returns temporary
```

You can make your code compile if you store pointer in a variable and make it non-temporary:

```
int main()    // main() must have return type int not void
{
   int x = 3;
   int &y = x;
   push(x);
   X *px = new X;
   push(px);
   push(y);
   delete px;
}
```

but most probably you chosen wrong type for the argument.

Details about references and why you can pass `int &y` and why `t` would not be a reference to reference in this case you can find [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Note: your code if you make it compile (changing type of `t` to const reference for example) would lead to memory leak, but that is out of scope of your question

Comment: Just one more question if I may: why if I change it to push (*(new X)) it does compile? I just deference the pointer but isn't it still a r-value/temporarily value?

Comment: No, when you dereference the pointer, result of dereference is l-value despite the fact that pointer itself is prvalue, that's how language works. It tries to help you to avoid mistakes but there are a lot of ways to shoot yourself into foot.